# Maximum call stack size exceeded on simple while( startsWith ), on Chrome/Firefox only

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I have a dead simple while loop that works just fine in Safari, and by logic it should also work on chrome.
It doesn't. In chrome, it works only the *first* time and the *subsequent times* it fails in a `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

The application:

1. a standard select input with options. Some options (text) start with a `-`. Others, don't
2. My JS acts on `change()` of said select input, and if the selected option `startsWith()` the `-`, then it checks its previous option and selects that, if that option does not start with `-`. Otherwise, it goes to the previous of the previous, etc, until an option without `-` is found.

This is the dummy sample code:

**Select Field Input**

```
<select name="my-select" class="my-class">
    <option value="0">All</option>
    <option value="value-1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value-1-child">- Value 1 child</option>
    <option value="value-2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value-2-child-1">- Value 2 child 1</option>
    <option value="value-2-child-2">- Value 2 child 2</option>
    <option value="value-3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

**The jQuery**

```
/**
 * Function to find previous option in select that does NOT have a "-" prefix.
 * If current option HAS such prefix, it scans previous options until one WITHOUT it is found (the parent) and selects that one.
 * If current option HAS NO such prefix, it can skip.
 */
function select_parent_instead_of_current() {
  jQuery('select[name="my-select"]').change(function(){

      if ( jQuery.trim( jQuery('select option:selected').text() ).startsWith('-') ) {

          var a = jQuery('select option:selected').prev();

          while ( jQuery.trim( a.text() ).startsWith('-') ) {
            a = a.prev();
          }

          if ( jQuery.trim( a.text() ).startsWith('-') === false ) {
            jQuery('select[name="my-select"] option:contains(' + jQuery.trim( a.text() ) + ')').attr('selected', 'selected').change();
          }

      }

  });
}

/**
 * Fire the function on ready, and other events I require
 */
jQuery( document ).on( 'custom_event_one custom_event_two ready', function( event, data ) {
    select_parent_instead_of_current();
});
```

Clicking on `- Value 2 child 2` option, should select `Value 2`, and this should work no matter if we click once or 100 times on that option.
In safari, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
jQuery('select[name="my-select"] option:contains(' + jQuery.trim( a.text() ) + ')').attr('selected', 'selected').change();
```

is causing problems. Use [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), which has been available everywhere for more than a decade, instead of jQuery's deprecated and unhelpful [`jQuery.trim`.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/), and change the `selected` *property* of the element to true with `.prop` instead of `.attr`. With that, the recursive `.change()` call won't result in an overflow. You can also consider using `$` instead of `jQuery` so as to be less verbose.

```js
function select_parent_instead_of_current() {
  const select = $('select[name="my-select"]');
  select.change(() => {
    // Either repeat [name="my-select"] again to make sure the right <select> is chosen
    // Or save the select in a variable name beforehand and .find
    const option = select.find('option:selected');
    if (!option.text().trim().startsWith('-')) {
      // reduce indentation hell by returning early
      return;
    }
    // consider using a more precise variable name than `a`
    let prevOption = option.prev();
    while (prevOption.text().startsWith('-')) {
      prevOption = prevOption.prev();
    }
    if (!prevOption.text().trim().startsWith('-')) {
      prevOption.prop('selected', true).change();
    }
  });
}

select_parent_instead_of_current();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my-select" class="my-class">
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="value-1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value-1-child">- Value 1 child</option>
  <option value="value-2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value-2-child-1">- Value 2 child 1</option>
  <option value="value-2-child-2">- Value 2 child 2</option>
  <option value="value-3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Rather than checking the text, a quicker option would be to check whether the element being iterated over has `child` in its value, and use `.prevAll` to select previous siblings that don't have `child` in the attribute.

```js
function select_parent_instead_of_current() {
  const select = $('select[name="my-select"]');
  select.change(() => {
    const option = select.find('option:selected');
    if (option.is('[value*=child]')) {
      option
        .prevAll(':not([value*=child])')
        .eq(0) // only want the first matching sibling
        .prop('selected', true)
        .change();
    }
  });
}

select_parent_instead_of_current();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="my-select" class="my-class">
  <option value="0">All</option>
  <option value="value-1">Value 1</option>
  <option value="value-1-child">- Value 1 child</option>
  <option value="value-2">Value 2</option>
  <option value="value-2-child-1">- Value 2 child 1</option>
  <option value="value-2-child-2">- Value 2 child 2</option>
  <option value="value-3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works. I do not understand why my solution does not work on chrome, but does, on safari.
In any case, a few notes: `child` is just a dummy placeholder. The real values are only distinguishable by the `-` so I went with your solution 1. There, I had to fix one tiny thing which is `while (prevOption.text().startsWith('-')) {` needs to be `trim()` ed as well (since my values of course are a bit more dumb and use a `  -` to indent the child options).

Otherwise, that solution works as a charm. NOT Really sure why, though, as by logic it seems what I did, just more clean code.

Comment: Continue above comment: So the core issue on my code is how I select the option, using .attr()? Again, I do not get why in Safari that is just fine, in chrome it overflows (for no apparent reason, since the while() condition is pretty clear). Again, thanks for your help. Greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.attr` changes the *attribute*, which can be thought of as the HTML markup for the element. But each element has its own independent markup. If you make set multiple `<option>`s to have the `selected` attribute, it is now ambiguous as to which element should *actually* appear selected in the page (outside of multiselect option). It seems that Safari's behavior in that ambiguous situation is different from Chrome's and Firefox's. Best approach: don't use `.attr` and don't get into the ambiguous situation to begin with.